# Why npx create-react-app dont install anything?

Tags: node.js, npm

I cannot install any npm packages. I try create new CRA. But terminal show nothing, no error and no warnings have. I dont know why it was. Help me please. I use `v2RayN` trojan vpn. It work only browser well. It dont work at windows termaninal. I think for that dont get packages. I disable or enable vpn so dont show any warnings or errors.
How to fix this?

Comment: Try to clear the NPM cache. Using `npm cache clean –force` and try it again

Comment: I think -force error. npm ERR! arg Argument starts with non-ascii dash, this is probably invalid: –force
npm WARN Not Found: –force  get this error

Comment: Now i run `npm cache clean --force` it too not working